# Pandas; comparing one dataframe column's values with a list's elements

Tags: pandas, string, list, dataframe, compare

I have a column in my df, lets say df["col1"] and one list of elements, lets say lst =[.....]
But the col1 and the list elements are strings. I would like to check whether the values are the same without taking into account the ordering.
E.g,

```
df["col1"] = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1
lst = [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,1]
```

This should give me True, because I have the same exact elements, just in different order.
In case the length is different or anything else, it should give me False.

Thank you.

Comment: `(df.col1.sort_values() == sorted(lst)).all()`

Answer (score 3):

If you have unique values, use `set` operations:

```
set(df['col1']) == set(lst)
```

else, compare the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) of elements:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(df['col1']) == Counter(lst)
```

Both operations should have a `O(n)` complexity.